# Arquivo .json não é criado em angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

Criei um `controller` e um serviço. Seguem eles, para exemplificar o que está acontecendo:

#### Controller

```
eventsApp.controller('EditEventController',
function EditEventController($scope, eventData){

    $scope.event = {};

    $scope.saveEvent = function (event,newEventForm){
        console.log(newEventForm);
        if (newEventForm.$valid){
            eventData.save(event)
                .$promise.then(
                    function(response) {console.log('success',response)},
                    function(response) {console.log('failure',response)}
            );
        }
    };

    $scope.cancelEdit = function (){
        window.location = "EventDetails.html";
    }
});
```

#### Serviço

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($resource) {
var resource = $resource('data/event/:id'+'.json', {id:'@id'});
return {
    getEvent: function () {
        return resource.get({id:1});
    },
    save: function (event) {
        event.id = 999;
        return resource.save(event);
    }
};
});
```

O estranho é que o a mensagem é de `success` na console do Chrome, mas o conteúdo do form não é gravado no arquivo `.json`, que tem o ID pré-fixado por mim de 999, como especificado na linha `event,id = 999;` do serviço. Já verifiquei o caminho e permissões no sistema de arquivo e ambos estão corretos. O estranho é que para obter a mensagem de `success` na console do browser, tive de criar o arquivo `999.json` no sistema de arquivos, pois antes disto, quando o método `save` foi executado, ele retornou erro 404, de URL não encontrada (achei estranho, pois se estou querendo fazer um post, porque é feito um get antes?)

Comment: você pode iniciar seu controle como uma função anônima, em vez de:  `... function EditEventController($scope, eventData){ ...`, use `function($scope, eventData) {...`

Comment: Jogue numa variável antes de enviar o recurso. É uma questão de ordem de requisição, acredito. Você primeiro recebe a url completa, depois vc faz a requisição get. Não dá pra fazer os dois ao mesmo tempo... não tem como vc receber a id, de algo que ainda não existiu.

Answer (score 1):

O erro 404 ocorre porque o recurso especificado não existe no servidor (ou um manipulador para o recurso). Erros 404 não são apenas relacionados com o método GET, e sim com todos os métodos do HTTP.

Por isso, inclusive, que quando criou o recurso `999.json` no seu servidor, no caminho especificado, ele deixou de retornar o status 404 (acredito que passou a retornaro 200).

O problema, portanto, esta na sua implementação no servidor.

**HTTP**

No seu comentário, você disse que não possui nada no servidor.

O protocolo HTTP, utilizado nas requisições Web (seja HTTP 1, 1.1 ou 2), possui alguns métodos de acesso. Os mais utilizados em aplicações tradicionais são o GET e o POST, mas com a difusão do desenvolvimento de APIs RESTful, os métodos PUT e DELETE passaram também a ser muito utilizados.

Estes nomes, não são apenas nomes bonitinhos. Eles possuem uma semântica. Simplificadamente:

1. GET: pede uma representação de um determinado recurso;
2. POST: pede que o webserver armazene os dados enviados subordinados ao recurso especificado (pense como "alterar o recurso");
3. PUT: pede que os dados sejam armazenados como o recurso especificado (pense como "criar um recurso");
4. DELETE: pede que o recurso seja removido.

O que é um `recurso`? Recurso é especificado na URL após o domínio e antes do fragmento e da consulta e identifica "algo" no servidor. Por exemplo:

```
http://www.dominio.com.br/meu/recurso?consulta=exemplo#fragmento
```

- `http://`: esquema;
- `www.dominio.com.br`: domínio;
- `/meu/recurso`: caminho do recurso;
- `?consulta=exemplo`: consulta;
- `#fragmento`: fragmento.

Por padrão, o HTTP não especifica o que é este "recurso" no servidor: ele é completamente do domínio da sua aplicação web. Ou seja, ele pode ser um arquivo, um registro no banco de dados, ou algo muito mais complexo (ou mais simples).

Da mesma forma, praticamente todos os códigos de status podem ser retornados por cada um destes métodos. Muitas vezes, estes status dependem também do domínio da aplicação.

Ou seja, uma requisição POST pode retornar um 404 caso o recurso não seja encontrado. Um PUT porém, é mais incomum de retornar 404, pois se espera que ele não exista no servidor e deseja-se criá-lo.

Então o correto seria usar PUT na sua requisição? O mais correto seria sim utilizar PUT, e não POST. Mas só isso não irá resolver.

O HTTP nada mais que padroniza a troca de mensagens entre o cliente o servidor. Servidores web, como Nginx, Apache e qualquer outro, apenas implementa esta troca de mensagens.

Cabe a você implementar como responder a cada uma das mensagens. E cabe a você seguir os padrões de status definidos pelo HTTP.

Mas porque o GET funciona? Porque quando você instala o servidor, você especifica um caminho chamado `DocumentRoot`, que é (simplificadamente) uma pasta no sistema de arquivos entendida como o `/` dos seus recursos. Todas as requisições que chegarem no servidor, serão processadas relativas a este diretório. Por padrão, os servidores web entregam arquivos (requisição GET) caso eles existam (status 200), ou retornam erro do contrário (404, 403, etc). Por isso que ao criar o arquivo `999.json` você passou a receber um status 200.

Mas repare que, apesar de tudo, suas requisições POST *provavelmente* não alteravam propriamente dito o recurso. Isto ocorre porque apesar do recurso existir, o servidor não sabe o que fazer com ele.

Então o que fazer? Você deve implementar o seu manipulador de recursos para este recurso, e ele sim realizar o trabalho devido.

Como fazer? Cada linguagem é de um jeito, e o servidor escolhido (Apache, etc) influencia na implementação. JetBeans deve ser JSP, procure no Google. Já fiz, mas não lembro nem como cria o projeto. Não é difícil não, e geralmente é um serviço chato e repetitivo.

Espero que a explicação tenha clareado um pouco. Dê uma olhada na página da Wikipedia sobre HTTP (em inglês). Por mais que existam inúmeras pessoas por aí desenvolvendo pra web, a grande maioria (sem dúvida!) faz tudo de qualquer jeito, não sabe os "porques". Entender o protocolo (só o básico, calma!) é o primeiro passo para se tornar um bom desenvolvedor!

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Vinícius, obrigado pelo seu retorno. Na verdade, eu não tenho nada no servidor, somente estou fazendo testes com um HTML que chama arquivos JS de dentro dele. Desenvolvo usando o WebStorm da JetBeans. Não tenho nenhum servidor de mercado, como IIS, NodeJS, Apache. A engine de WebServer é provida pelo próprio WebStorm. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: É este o problema. Vou editar a pergunta sobre o funcionamento básico do HTTP.